# Migrate from EC2 to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to host a new web application (I devised it but did not code it).  I went with EC2 but after a very short time have realised that I am out of my depth.  I understand Elastic Beanstalk is easier to get to grips with.

The question I have is can I move what I have already in EC2 to be managed by Elastic Beanstalk, and is it even necessary to 'move' anything? (I ask this because my understanding of Eleastic Beanstalk is that it is a management tool for EC2).

If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes you can migrate from "self managed" EC2 to an "AWS Managed" EC2 with Elastic Beanstalk.

It is not a click button exercise and there are a number of things to consider

- Is my platform supported in Elastic Beanstalk? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html)
- What is my current OS? Note Elastic Beanstalk uses Amazon Linux 2, which is a variant of Centos/RHEL
- You will need to package up the application into a .zip that Elastic Beanstalk will uncompress and install onto an EC2 system. This may include sysprep steps such as installing packages, and placing the app in appropriate folder.

Overall Elastic Beanstalk is a solid candidate if you are looking to reduce complexity, but does come with limitations currently such as not being up to date with the all the latest aws service. (EBS GP3 support is not yet available)